# $routeProvider doesn't pass the controller to my template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to load a template dinamically in angular using ngRoute...
The problem is that i Use this code :

(app.js route configuration)

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/password", {
        templateUrl : "../password/index.html",
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs : 'loginCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch : false
    });
});
```

This is the HTML template (../password/index.html)

```
<div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
   ....
 <form ng-submit="loginCtrl.controllaPassword()">
   ....
</div>
```

(app.js controller )

```
this.controllaPassword = function(){
    alert("kuajia");
};
```

At the moment the code appear on the main html page(login.html) where i declare ng-app, but it doesn't shpw the alert.

Comment: et_pb_row et_pb_row_0 this div is inside of LoginCtrl?

Comment: no it is inside ../password/index.html, but i want to load this HTML code inside of login.html(the main code where i declared ng-app on HTML tag and where I have attached all the scripts( also app.js where i wrote the controller))

Comment: if the element that want to use some controller of your app isnt inside of controller will not work, i thing inside your template have declare your controller not on login.html

Comment: tried, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You problem seems to be in typing.
You controller alias(controllerAs) name is not the same in your html template.

Try this html template as below.

```
<div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
   ....
 <form ng-submit="LoginCtrl.controllaPassword()">
   ....
</div>
```

Comment: Everything seems to be good, you just need to go to the password page, in order to execute that alert.

Make sure u are using ng-view directive properly.